# VBA only grabbing one chart to ppt when I want all?

Tags: excel, vba, charts, powerpoint, transfer

I'm an amateur coder. I'm trying to put something together to transfer all charts in an excel file to different slides on a powerpoint. I've tested several modules online (some from here as well). I've found this one below to be the most comprehensive for me so far. I have 3 graphs on a worksheet and for some reason I can't figure out, the code only copies one graph (first created), makes  new slide and sticks it on that second slide. No idea what's going on, any help would be appreciated:

```html
Sub ChartsAndTitlesToPresentation()
' Set a VBE reference to Microsoft PowerPoint Object Library

Dim PPApp As PowerPoint.Application
Dim PPPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim PPSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
Dim PresentationFileName As Variant
Dim SlideCount As Long
Dim iCht As Integer
Dim sTitle As String

' Reference existing instance of PowerPoint
Set PPApp = GetObject(, "Powerpoint.Application")
' Reference active presentation
Set PPPres = PPApp.ActivePresentation
PPApp.ActiveWindow.ViewType = ppViewSlide

For iCht = 1 To ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Count
    With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(iCht).Chart
        
        ' get chart title
        If .HasTitle Then
            sTitle = .ChartTitle.Text
        Else
            sTitle = ""
        End If
        
        ' remove title (or it will be redundant)
        .HasTitle = False
        
        ' copy chart as a picture
        .CopyPicture _
            Appearance:=xlScreen, Size:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
        
        ' restore title
        If Len(sTitle) > 0 Then
            .HasTitle = True
            .ChartTitle.Text = sTitle
        End If
    End With
    
    ' Add a new slide and paste in the chart
    SlideCount = PPPres.Slides.Count
    Set PPSlide = PPPres.Slides.Add(SlideCount + 1, ppLayoutTitleOnly)
    PPApp.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide PPSlide.SlideIndex
    With PPSlide
        ' paste and select the chart picture
        .Shapes.Paste.Select
        ' align the chart
        PPApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignCenters, True
        PPApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignMiddles, True
        .Shapes.Placeholders(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = sTitle
    End With

Next

' Clean up
Set PPSlide = Nothing
Set PPPres = Nothing
Set PPApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: The basic idea looks right. Have you stepped through it in the debugger to see if it's looping over the chart objects correctly?

Comment: Please give us some more information about what is going and what not. I have some general recommendations: Try to avoid "active...." especially when you switch between two applications (even when microsoft uses it in its examples). Try to avoid "with object" when you run in problems. Give your objects names and refer to them by their name. Then you have a good chance to find misbehaviour.

Comment: >> For iCht = 1 To ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Count  ... Are all of your charts on the active worksheet?  If they're on other worksheets or on chartsheets, this won't pick them up.

Comment: Hi All, Thank you so much for your input. I tried all your advice and found that for some reason, it was the "Select" option in the Paste line. My guess is that it had trouble returning to excel with an image selected?

Comment: Sounds like the paste was overwriting the selection (the previous graph) although I don't know if that fits with the first graph being the one to remain at the end.